# Programmatically rendering a web UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a load of `UserControl` objects (`ascx` files) in their own little project. I then reference this project in two projects: The REST API (which is a class library project) and the main website.

I'm sure this would be easy in the website, simply use `Controls.Add` in any `Panel` or ASP.NET control would work.

However, what about the API? Is there any way I can render the HTML of this control, simply by knowing the type of the control? The [RenderControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.rendercontrol.aspx) method doesn't write any HTML to the writer as the control's life cycle hasn't even started.

*Please bare in mind that I don't have the controls in the web project, so I don't have a virtual path to the `ascx` file. So the [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx) method won't work here.*

All the controls actually derive from the same base control. Is there anything I can do from within this base class that will allow me to load the control from a completely new instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I have done recently, works well, but understand postbacks will not work if you use it inside your ASP.NET app.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string GetMyUserControlHtml()
 {
     return  RenderUserControl("Com.YourNameSpace.UI", "YourControlName");
 }

 public static string RenderUserControl(string assembly,
             string controlName)
 {
        FormlessPage pageHolder = 
                new FormlessPage() { AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath }; //allow for "~/" paths to resolve

        dynamic control = null;

        //assembly = "Com.YourNameSpace.UI"; //example
        //controlName = "YourCustomControl"
        string fullyQaulifiedAssemblyPath = string.Format("{0}.{1},{0}", assembly, controlName);

        Type type = Type.GetType(fullyQaulifiedAssemblyPath);
        if (type != null)
        {
            control = pageHolder.LoadControl(type, null);
            control.Bla1 = "test"; //bypass compile time checks on property setters if needed
            control.Blas2 = true;

        }                          

        pageHolder.Controls.Add(control);
        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);
        return output.ToString();
 }


public class FormlessPage : Page
{
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking good rick. Just trying to implement that now in my structure. One thing I've noticed though - `HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();`. This variable is never used, because `form.Controls.Add` is commented out? Am I missing something?

Comment: I will update, there is a way to do with a regular form, but if your control doesn't have a form tag or you don't add one programatically, you will get a runtime error.  That is what the FormLessPage class bypasses for you.