# Loop through DataAdapter to Generate HTML table

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following in code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GenerateHtml(string id)
{
    //return id;
    DataView vwMain2;
    try
    {
        DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
        using (IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection())
        {
            string sSQL;
            sSQL = "select top 20                " + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + " ASSISTING_FILE_ID, DATE_ENTERED, CLIENT_CLAIM_NUM, PRIMARY_INSURED, PRIMARY_CLAIMANT, LOB_ID, FILE_STATUS, BRANCH_NAME," + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + " OWNERS_FIRST_NAME, OWNERS_LAST_NAME, OWNERS_NAME, OWNERS_EMAIL, OWNERS_OFFICE_PHONE, OWNERS_FAX_PHONE, OWNERS_CELL_PHONE" + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + "  from vwFILES_DetailViewWithOwners" + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + " where 1 = 1                    " + ControlChars.CrLf;
            //+ " where 1 = 1 and WEB_USER_ID = '" + Security.USER_ID.ToString() + "'" + ControlChars.CrLf;
            using (IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL;

                using (DbDataAdapter da = dbf.CreateDataAdapter())
                {
                    ((IDbDataAdapter)da).SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        vwMain2 = dt.DefaultView;
                        GridView2.DataSource = vwMain2;

                            GridView2.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SplendidError.SystemError(new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0), ex.Message);
        //lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }

}
```

I want to loop through that and create an HTML table in the following format:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Column Header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What is the best way to do this?  I want to return the HTML once it is generated.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to call this like a webservice?

Comment: I am calling this from my jQuery function which will output the HTML once it is generated.  I was initially going to use an ASP.NET GridView, but apparently that won't work...  So, the plan is to simply create an HTML table like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use a stringBuilder and piece together the HTML by hand in some loops.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append('<table><tbody>');

foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
     sb.append('<tr><th>' + r["ColumnHeader"] + '</th></tr>');
     sb.append('<tr><th>' + r["ColumnData"] + '</th></tr>');
}

 sb.append('</tbody></table>');


  return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how to apply your solution in this scenario?

Comment: Something like this should get you going in the right direction

Comment: Re:  Your edit:  Where would I put that?  Inside `using ( DataTable dt = new DataTable() )` ?

Comment: Yep yep, right inside the using. Sorry I probably should have copied the whole method down

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call this like a WebService (e.g: for a jQuery ajax call), you have several choice:

1. I don't like this particularly, but using [UpdatePanels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx) may be an option.
2. If SEO isn't an issue, and you just need to render a table on the client side, you can just transfer a JSON object and do JavaScript code to create the DOM elements
3. If you still want to use the GridView, [you can use a UserControl, load it dynamically and use the rendered string to send it back](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2007/11/05/dynamically-render-a-web-user-control.aspx) (Obviously, the UserControl would have the code you just wrote above in it):

Code:

```
Control report;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
Html32TextWriter hw = new Html32TextWriter(sw);

report = LoadControl("WebUserControl.ascx");
report.RenderControl(hw);

report = LoadControl("WebUserControl.ascx"); 

((IReportUserControl)report).LoadReport(); //Initialize the control 

report.RenderControl(hw);
```

[There is also a Stackoverflow post on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088427/programatically-rendering-a-web-usercontrol).

4. Andrew's answer is a different and simple approach and will work as well.
5. Also, worth mentioning that MVC would probably fix a bunch of problems when doing those kind of things.

Comment: Thanks, Allov.  That is a lot to consider.  I think I will go with the simpler approach, but this is educational :)

Comment: Re:  Your MVC comment:  Yes I totally agree!  I wish I was in MVC right now!  This is a legacy app...