# Unable to access user control public properties from generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, httphandler

Following is my generic handler's code. This code compiles and converts user control named `NavigationMenu.ascx` into HTML and sends it to the calling page:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="GetMenu" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


public class GetMenu : IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //--some other code
    string markup = getUserControlMarkup(0);
    context.Response.Write(markup);
}
public string getUserControlMarkup(int menuType)
{
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    using (System.Web.UI.Page page = new System.Web.UI.Page())
    {
        System.Web.UI.UserControl userControl = null;
        userControl = (System.Web.UI.UserControl)page.LoadControl("~/user controls/NavigationMenu.ascx");

        Type type = userControl.GetType();
        page.Controls.Add(userControl);
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

This is design code for user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NavigationMenu.ascx.cs" Inherits="NM.user_controls_NavigationMenu"  %>
<!--Some html -->
```

and following is its cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NM
{
    public partial class user_controls_NavigationMenu : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public int menuType = -1;
        public int selectedItem = -1;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Some code
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to access `menuType` and `selectedItem` from generic handler. I tried accessing them like this:

```
((NM.user_controls_NavigationMenu)userControl).menuType=0;
```

But Visual Studio is unable to find NM namespace. I tried adding the generic handler class in the NM namespace but still the same problem persists. Please tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by myself. I converted my project to Web Application by right clicking the project in Solution Explorer and selecting "Convert to Web Application". And it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a usercontrol instance to a asp.net page instance "without a form" will result in an error similar to the below one. 
[image]

The solution for this is to derive the `Page` class and [override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8088779/145682) `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` method.

```
public class FormlessPage : Page
{
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }
}
```

Replace `Page` with the above class.

```
var pageHolder = new FormlessPage();
pageHolder.Controls.Add(pageHolder.LoadControl(path));
```

As for your main issue with VS not allowing you to reference to the UserControl class, open the class view and find the usercontrol. This way you can understand the namespace hierarchy easily.